# The content in my Nextjs app is not updating after deployment

Tags: deployment, mern, vercel, next.js13, updating

```
 The content in my Nextjs app is not updating after deployment. 
its being deployed as static in Vercel. 
but when I try locally it works absolutely fine. 
However it show the new content or updating 
after the re-deployment.[deploying as static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trWjv.jpg) 
How to fix it?

import Connect from "../../../dbConfig/connect";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
import Post from "../../../models/postSchema";


Connect()

export async function GET(req, res){
    try{
        const posts = await Post.find()
        if(posts){
            
            const response = NextResponse.json(posts)
            return response
        }else{
            const response = NextResponse.json({
                message: `requested data cannot be obtained. The Database is empty`
            })
            return response
        }
    }catch(e){
        const response = NextResponse.json({
            message: `Internal server error - ${e}`
        })
        return response
    }
}
```

it's not getting updated data after deployment. gets only the previous data, until redeployment. this data is captured using a useEffect hook to show in the app.

```
useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('/api/data').then(({data})=>{
            setData(data)           
        })
    },[])
```

but the view of app that came after the deployment not contain newly uploaded data after.